# Não consigo colocar imagem em um JButton

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

Tentei colocar a imagem mas só dá `NullPointerException`, já tentei criar uma pasta chamada `img` dentro da pasta `src` e apontar para lá porém sem sucesso também. Não sei o que eu posso estar fazendo de errado. A imagem está no diretório.

Segue o código:

```
public class GuiTeste {
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
JButton bTOrdenar = new JButton();

public void iniciar() {
bTOrdenar.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("img/iconOrganize.png")));
frame.setSize(520,120);
frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.NORTH,bTOrdenar);
frame.setResizable(false);
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.setVisible(true);
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    GuiTeste teste= new GuiTeste();
    teste.iniciar();
}
```

}

Tentei também o comando:

```
Image img = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("img/IconLoad2.bmp")); bTOrdenar.setIcon(new ImageIcon(img));
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Por favor, apresente um código que seja um **[mcve]** para que seja possivel testar e executar.

Comment: Desculpa, pelo erro, já coloquei o código completo

Comment: Não ta completo, como vamos executar isso? Sugiro que leia o link q enviei e siga as orientacoes explicadas nele.

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger ele ja esclareceu nos comentarios da resposta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seu código não é reproduzível, mas para funcionar, a imagem precisa estar no pacote `img` no mesmo nível da classe dentro do seu projeto na IDE. Se não existir um pacote `img`, a imagem não será localizada e estourará nullpointer. Verifique em seu projeto se o pacote existe e se encontra no mesmo nível da classe que está tentando acessá-la.

Para exemplificar a hierarquia num projeto sem nomeação de pacote(não recomendável):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estando desse jeito, classe e pacote `img` dentro do mesmo pacote, o código executa sem erros.

---

Conforme mencionado nos comentários e como dá pra ver na figura, está utilizando uma hierarquia de pacotes própria no eclipse, e o ideal é sempre informar o caminho completo, no seu caso, seria:

```
getClass().getResource("/br/com/williamcasa/servicodeordenacao/icons/iconOrganize.png");
```

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger nunca tive problemas dessa forma em nenhuma das IDEs mais utilizadas.

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger isso só é relevante se ele estiver programando sem IDE, e isso nao foi informado na pergunta.

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger então vamos aguardar que o interessado, no caso o OP, se manifeste a respeito desse imbroglio, certo? ;)

Comment: Estou usando o Eclipse, realmente não tinha o pacote dentro da IDE, eu criei e coloquei as imagens pra lá mais ainda da erro. meus pacotes possuem nome com ponto, por exemplo o pacote que eu criei é :br.com.williamcasa.servicodeordenacao.icons. Será tem problema? depois apontei para "icons/iconOrganize.png" testei também "/icons/iconOrganize.png" sem sucesso.

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger esclarecido acima, a resposta ainda é invalida?

Comment: @WilliamFerreira o melhor é sempre fornecer o caminho completo do pacote, no seu caso, seria `/br/com/williamcasa/servicodeordenacao/icons/iconOrganize.png`

Comment: Funcionou! Muito Obrigado!! no caso tive que por uma / antes do br, quando coloquei "/br/com/williamcasa/servicodeordenacao/icons/iconOrganize.png" funcionou!

Comment: @WilliamFerreira se a resposta lhe ajudou, voce pode aceita-la clicando no `v`, assim ela servirá de referencia para outros usuarios com semelhante problema.

Comment: Eu preciso deixar em uma resposta que funcionou para deixar de ajuda para os outros?

Comment: @WilliamFerreira não é necessário, somente aceitar já demonstra isso. Se acha q devo adicionar algo na resposta, me avise que edito e adiciono ;)

Comment: pode colocar para usar o caminho completo do pacote? tipo /br/com/williamcasa/servicodeordenacao/icons/iconOrganize.png. Nas pesquisas que fiz só mostrava pasta/imagem.png, acho que essa informação e a de criar o pacote na IDE resolveram o problema

Comment: @WilliamFerreira pronto, editado